# Why I'm not receiving any output from the Magento CLI?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, cli

When I run `bin/magento` in my server I'm not receiving any output, so I'm not able to see any possible issue.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's because of your PHP version, make sure that your PHP version is a version supported by your Magento 2 version.

You can check the [Magento 2.3 technology stack requirements](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).